# Why is my .Net Core API not receiving data from request payload?

Tags: c#, angular, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm building a Angular website with .Net Core API as backend. When I post a new postcode my Angular service sends the data correctly, but my API is not receiving the data.

The edit (put) works fine using similar code.

Add (post): [postcode values are null in Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bc2FY.png)
, [postcodes values are filled in Request Payload](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XAbwK.png)

Edit (put): [postcode values are not null in Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RsdyU.png), [the request payload of put](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h35OQ.png)

PostCodeController:

```
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    public class PostcodeController : Controller
    {
        IPostCodeAcces<PostcodeVerwerking, int> _postcodeRepo;
        public PostcodeController(IPostCodeAcces<PostcodeVerwerking, int>p)
        {
            _postcodeRepo = p;
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult Post([FromForm]PostcodeVerwerking postcode)
        {
            int res = _postcodeRepo.AddPostcode(postcode); 
            if (res != 0)
            {
                return Ok();
            }
            return Forbid();
        }

        [HttpPut("{id}")]
        public IActionResult Put(int id, [FromForm] PostcodeVerwerking p)
        {
            if (id == p.Id)
            {
                int res = _postcodeRepo.UpdatePostcode(id, p);
                if (res != 0)
                {
                    return Ok(res);
                }
                return NotFound();
            }
            return NotFound();
        }
    }
```

Angular Service:

```
  putPostcode(id, formdata: FormData): Observable<PostcodeVerwerking>{
    return this.http.put<PostcodeVerwerking>(this.apiUrl + "/" + id, formdata);
  }

  postPostcode(formdata: FormData): Observable<PostcodeVerwerking>{
    return this.http.post<PostcodeVerwerking>(this.apiUrl, formdata);
  }
```

Comment: Please paste your code into the question **as text** so we can copy and paste it.  We cannot work on images of code.

Comment: Check the case. You're sending `postcode`, but your model is looking for `Postcode` from the looks of it

Comment: @user184994 this was indeed the case, thank you.

Comment: You might want to look into Swagger/OpenAPI. Specifically NSwag, to both generate the API specification at ASP.NET side and the client at Angular side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it. I simply had to change `postcode` in post in the controller to `p` and it worked.

Wrong:

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Post([FromForm]PostcodeVerwerking postcode)
{
   int res = _postcodeRepo.AddPostcode(postcode); 
   if (res != 0)
   {
       return Ok();
   }
    return Forbid();
}
```

Right:

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Post([FromForm]PostcodeVerwerking p)
{
   int res = _postcodeRepo.AddPostcode(p); 
   if (res != 0)
   {
      return Ok();
   }
   return Forbid();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose PostcodeVerwerking.Id is an `int` type property so it cannot be null. The serializer cannot bind null to the id property either, so the whole PostcodeVerwerking will be null in the controller. 
If you want to send null as the Id, you have to declare Id as `int?` like:

`public int? Id {get; set;}`